# Visual studio code turn off ES6 validation on specific folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint

I have a large project I am working on that uses ES6 Javascript. However a particular "plugins" folder still uses ES5 Javascript.

In Visual studio code any Javascript file I open that is within this "plugins" folder, it underlines everything red thinking there are syntax errors.

Is there a way I can tell Visual studio code not to lint the plugins folder as ES6?

I tried...
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript

I have tried adding an "jsconfig.json" in the root of the "plugins" folder with the following content(but it hasn't worked).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6"
},
  "exclude": [
    "plugins",
    "**/plugins/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a way for Visual Studio Code to just ignore linting a whole folder, but failing that, adding the following line to the top of each JS file does the job.

```
/*eslint-disable*/
```